# Nexus 5: How to automatically toggle Live Display in Cyanogenmod 12.1 nightly at a specific time?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.1-lollipop, automation, live-display

I have a Nexus 5 with the last CyanogenMod nightly (12.1 20150917). I have a bug with the live display. Since the auto mode doesn't switch automatically, I have installed Automate, an app that uses the Android API to do tasks.

To fix the bug, I would like to create a task to switch in the night mode at a specific time, but unfortunately, there isn't the Live Display in Automate. Is there a way to set the night mode through the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

A user named r3t3ch [provided](https://old.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/2yh6qw/cyanogenmod_livedisplay_settings/cre7gem/) the following solution on Reddit which I'm reproducing. Their answer was tested on a Moto X with CM 12.1.

To change [night/live] mode (Auto=2, Off=0, Day=4, Night=1):

```
adb shell settings put system display_temperature_mode 2
```

To change color temperature:

```
adb shell settings put system display_temperature_day 6500 settings put system display_temperature_night 3400
```

To change color calibration:

```
adb shell settings put system display_color_adjustment "0.8991 0.8689 1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Night mode set block](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/night_mode_set_state.html) should be able to toggle night mode.
There's no block for changing *Live Display*, but it might be possible to change the system settings for it, using the [System setting set block](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/system_setting_get.html), see the Reddit post [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/2yh6qw/cyanogenmod_livedisplay_settings/cre7gem/) for the possible setting names and values.